# How to go to help menu for C++ while using Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I used to use TurboC++ in my school.

If I had a doubt as to how to use a keyword or function (in the syntax or the order of arguments), I only had to write it on screen and right-click on the word and it would lead me to the help screen of that particular function or keyword. It also included an example program showing how it is implemented.

Does Xcode have any similar features for C++?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Xcode's Quick Help (triggered when Option-clicking a keyword) has a strong focus on Apple frameworks (AppKit, SwiftUI, Foundation) and on the Swift standard library, so I don't think it will be a lot of help for programming C++ (a quick test with a sample C++ program confirms that Quick Help doesn't find any results for functions from the C++ standard library or built-in data types). You may want to look for an alternative IDE.

Comment: @AdorableCherry Could you clarify whether you're using Xcode for Swift/Objective-C or actually for C++?  I.e. you write that you used to use TurboC++, that has this feature - but do you want to program in C++ now?

Comment: @jksoegaard Yes, I want to program in C++.

Comment: And I did try the "Quick Help" option, and it's just like how @jaume said; it doesn't show results for functions or data types from C++

Comment: @AdorableCherry You may want to give Microsoft Visual Studio Code (or as it is usually called, VSCode) a try. It is a nice IDE with support for many programming languages and it's free. You can download it from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac and then install this extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp for C++ support. If you find VSCode useful, I can rewrite this comment as an answer for you to accept...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Xcode has a similar feature. You can right-click on the function you want explained and select "Quick Help" - this will show a small popup with a summary of the function as well as a link for more documentation.

You can also use the keyboard shortcut Cmd-Opt-3 to open a sidebar on the right which will show the quick help at all times. I.e. if you move the cursor to a new function, the sidebar will automatically update with the help text for that function.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to make this work for functions from the C++ standard library 